# VBA - Count % cell if another cell matches a certain color

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table which has columns Name, % value, Color. I am trying to write a VBA code where if the color in a range of cell matches the color key it adds the % value. Essentially a Sum if formula. I got my first function to work when I wanted a countif VBA but when I add the additional variable (% amount range) it does not work.

I am fairly new to VBA so please can you assist me.

Thanks

```
'Count If the color in the cell matches the color key
Function GetColorCount(CountRange As Range, CountColor As Range)
'Dim is to declare variables
Dim CountColorValue As Integer
Dim TotalCount As Integer
CountColorValue = CountColor.Interior.ColorIndex
Set rCell = CountRange
For Each rCell In CountRange
    If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = CountColorValue Then
        TotalCount = TotalCount + 1
        End If
Next rCell
GetColorCount = TotalCount
End Function

'Sum the % amount in the range If the color in the cell matches the color key
Function ColorCountHolding(CountRange As Range, CountColor As Range, HoldingRange As Range)
' Dim is to declare variables
Dim CountColorValue As Integer
Dim TotalValueHolding As Integer
CountColorValue = CountColor.Interior.ColorIndex
Set hCell = HoldingRange
Set rCell = CountRange
For Each rCell In CountRange
    If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = CountColorValue Then
        TotalValueHolding = TotalValueHolding + Holding
        End If
Next rCell
ColorCountHolding = TotalValueHolding
End Function
```

Comment: First of all, you're likely going to need `Dim TotalValueHolding As Double`. Percentages don't tend to be integers.

Comment: Variable `Holding` is not getting a value anywhere. Seems that this is a cell in `HoldingRange` and you need the value from the same row where the color is equal to the `CountColorValue` ??

Comment: @Blackcat that is correct how could I do this please?

Answer (score 0):

I use the `Color` property instead of `ColorIndex`  this is a constant specific color on the palette.

```
'Sum the % amount in the range If the color in the cell matches the color key
Function ColorCountHolding(CountRange As Range, CountColor As Range, HoldingRange As Range)
' Dim is to declare variables
Dim CountColorValue As Long
Dim TotalValueHolding As Long
CountColorValue = CountColor.Interior.Color
Set hCell = HoldingRange
Set rcell = CountRange
For Each rcell In CountRange
    If rcell.Interior.Color = CountColorValue Then
        TotalValueHolding = TotalValueHolding + HoldingRange.Rows(rcell.Row)
        End If
Next rcell
ColorCountHolding = TotalValueHolding
End Function
```

Note: A8 has a slightly different color.

[image]